# Need help understanding Haskell recursive division function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
recdiv :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
recdiv x numlist divisors
    | numlist == [] = divisors
    | mod x (last numlist) == 0 = recdiv x (init numlist) ((last numlist):divisors)
    | otherwise = recdiv x (init numlist) (divisors)

divides :: Integer -> [Integer]
divides x
    | x == 0 = error "Visi skaiciai"
    | x > 0 = recdiv x [1..x] []
    | x < 0 = recdiv (abs x) [1..(abs x)] []
```

The purpose of this function is to find all of the divisors of an entered number.

I understand what happens in the divides function but I am having some trouble with the recdiv one.

As I understand in the third line we check whether the numlist is empty and if so, we make the divisors list empty as well.

However, I can't really understand what happens in the 4th and 5th lines. Could someone explain and help me understand?

Comment: This looks like an inefficient (and ugly) way to determine the divisors. The `last numlist` will for example take linear time in the size of the list. Typically list unpacking is done into the head and tail of the list.

Comment: There's also no need to distinguish positive arguments from negative ones. Just use absolute value.

Comment: It looks like `recdiv` is meant to be called with 1) the `x` to be divided, 2) a list `numlist` of potential divisors that have to be tested, and 3) a list `divisors` containing the divisors discovered so far. This is not the best approach, and the code is somehow poorly written (`last`, `==[]`, `init` are never a good sign).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a better version.

```
recdiv :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
recdiv x numlist = case numlist of
    [] -> []
    y : ys
      | mod x y == 0 = y : recdiv x ys
      | otherwise = recdiv x ys

divides :: Integer -> [Integer]
divides 0 = error "Visi skaiciai"
divides x = recdiv (abs x) [1..(abs x)]
```

But no one would write `recdiv` like that; they'd use

```
recdiv x = filter $ \y -> mod x y == 0
```

Don't try to understand the code you're looking at; just throw it away.

Comment: I've upvoted for the last sentence alone.